# htaccess rewrite

Tags: htaccess, ajax, redirects, rewrite

I have an endpoint that I need to rewrite semantically for various reasons. The problem is it is an API endpoint and carries POST data. If I use a 301 or 302, the redirect happens, but I lose all data associated. I have stripped my .htaccess file down to bare bones for testing and still can't get it working.

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # APIs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/add_product$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?ACT=20 [NE,L]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/(.*) /$1$2 [R=302,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am posting the JSON to the URL `https://www.mysite.com/api/add_product` and would like that to hit `https://www.mysite.com/index.php?ACT=20`

I can hit the ACT URL's fine but when I try to redirect/rewrite, I get either `No input file specified.` or a `404`.

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Quick thought, try status code 307: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect#99966 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638678/redirect-post-htaccess and

Comment: I tried 301, 302, and 307. It was my understanding that 307s were to allow the POST data, but no luck.  ;)

Comment: Is there some technical reason you can't use the ACT url as is? I can think of some work arounds but might seem like a lot more work...

Comment: Just to be able to add instructions that don't change when the addon is uninstalled/reinstalled. Also, I have another usage that will be called from several other sites. Remembering to go and update an unknown number of sites if I upgrade, debug, or uninstall/reinstall the addon in the host site, would be extremely problematic.